# How to decompose matrix to its composition of rotation and scaling?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, rotations, matrix-decomposition

[image]

Ans: for rotation and scaling factor are $\frac{\pi}{6}$ and 8 respectively.

I found a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3731249/decomposing-a-2-times-2-matrix-into-rotation-and-scaling), but it wasn't explaining it well. I also understand scale and rotation separately but cannot figure out how to derive rotation and scaling separately. Intuitively I thought it might be a scale of 4 as it's factorable, and a 90 degree rotation of $\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}$ as the signs (+/-) were aligned(pun not intended). I was completely wrong with my intution here.

---

I've worked out that the eigen values and that it is diagonalizable: $A=PDP^{-1}\rightarrow A=\begin{pmatrix}-i&i\\ \:1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}4\sqrt{3}+4i&0\\ 0&4\sqrt{3}-4i\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-i&i\\ \:1&1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$

How can we derive the rotation and scaling vector from here?

Found the below in the textbook, but cannot figure out how to apply it to find the rotation.

[image]

(My [failed attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuVUJ.jpg). I did not put it in as it would lengthen the question without significant focus or contribution.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The textbook's "Example $6$" gives you precisely the answer you need. In your case, we have $a = 4 \sqrt{3}$ and $b = -4$. We find that $r = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = \sqrt{48 + 16} = 8$. From what the example states, we have
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{4\sqrt{3} & -4\\4 & 4\sqrt{3}} &= C = r\pmatrix{a/r & -b/r\\b/r & a/r}
= \pmatrix{r&0\\0&r}\pmatrix{a/r & -b/r\\b/r & a/r}
\\ & = 
\pmatrix{8 & 0\\0 & 8}
\pmatrix{\sqrt{3}/2 & -1/2\\ 1/2 & \sqrt{3}/2} =
\pmatrix{8&0\\0&8} \pmatrix{\cos \varphi & -\sin\varphi\\ \sin \varphi & \cos \varphi}.
\end{align}
So, all that remains is to find the angle $\varphi$ such that $\cos\varphi = \sqrt{3}/2$ and $\sin \varphi = 1/2$.

Alternatively, you have already found that the eigenvalues are of the form $\lambda = 4\sqrt{3}\pm 4i$. As the example states, the scaling factor is the magnitude $|\lambda|$, and the angle is the argument of $\lambda$. In general, the argument of a complex number $a + bi$ can be found as $\arg(a + bi) = \tan^{-1}(b/a)$.

Comment: Thx @Ben Grossman its what I needed, a concrete example. My clarification questions are: (1) Textbook also says $r=\lambda=a \pm bi$ (which should be $r=\lambda = 4\sqrt{3} \pm 4i$..?). How did that become $r= |\lambda|=\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = \sqrt{48 + 16} = 8$? Is $C=r\begin{pmatrix}\frac{a}{r}&-\frac{b}{r}\\ \frac{b}{r}&\frac{a}{r}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}r&0\\ 0&r\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{a}{r}&-\frac{b}{r}\\ \:\frac{b}{r}&\frac{a}{r}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}r&0\\ \:0&r\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}cos\:\varphi &-sin\:\varphi \:\\ sin\:\varphi \:&cos\:\varphi \:\end{pmatrix}$...

Comment: ... is it just one of those formulas we got to remember, then solve for what the theta is? Looks like using the first method I don't even need eigenvalues or vectors?.. // (2) As for the alternative method using augmented complex matrices, unfortunately, isn't something I learned yet, and seem... complex.

Comment: @nvs To your first question: you textbook did **not** say $r = \lambda$ (at least not in the example that you shared); it said that $r = |\lambda|$.

Comment: @nvs To your second question, I suspect that the homework question was looking to have you apply the result of example 6, but not to have you memorize this result. That said, I think that it is useful to memorize that the matrix for a counterclockwise rotation by $\varphi$ is given by
$$
\pmatrix{\cos \varphi & -\sin \varphi\\ \sin \varphi & \cos \varphi}.
$$

Comment: re: Qn (1): the textbook said $r = |\lambda| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$, but if $\lambda = a\pm bi$, then $r = |\lambda|=|a\pm bi|$...? //(2)got it will do and many thanks again!

Comment: @nvs That's right. Note that $|a + bi| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$. Similarly, $|a - bi| = \sqrt{a^2 + (-b)^2} = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.

Comment: I see, got it. Looks like i really need to brush up on my complex numbers..!